# How do I set a default, max and min value for an integerfield Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator 
class Match(models.Model):
    overs = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(100)])
```

I've tried using the PositiveIntegerField but I believe that you cannot set a max value for that through Django - I'm not sure.

Comment: "I have tried using the PositiveIntegerField". So what did you find? Why do you believe it is not possible to set a max value? Have you read the [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/validators/) docs? What is the code you've posted in question for?

Comment: How can you add Max and Min in ***views.py*** or in Javascript?

Answer (score 116):

[`PositiveIntegerField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#positiveintegerfield) ensures no integer less than 0 will be accepted. Your validators seem to handle the minimum and maximum values correctly. All you are missing is [`default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#default) for the default value. So something like

```
overs = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(100)])
```

Comment: But how do you restrict the input range to between 1 and 100 in the UI?

Comment: @alias51 you would need to do that on the front-end. You could pass the `attrs` property to the field here and specify [the range you want](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range).

Answer (score 0):

Since the aim is to create an Integer Field with max and min values, another solution could be to create a select box with numbers from 1 through 100 instead of an input field where the value has to be validated later.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator 
class Match(models.Model):
    overs = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=((i,i) for i in range(1, 101)))
```

[image: demo]